# Hibernate inverse join for composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to hibernate.

I have the following situation,

```
@Entity(name="A")
Class A {
   @Id
   int id;

   Set<B> listB;
}

@Entity(name="B")
Class B {
   @Id
   CompositebPK bPk;
}

Class CompositebPK {
   @Column(name="id")
   int aId;
   @Column(name="user_name")
   String uname;
}

@Entity (name = "user")
Class User {
   @Column (name ="user_name")
   String uname;
}
```

table Structures is as follows,

```
Table A:
int id

Table B:
int id
String uname

User:
String uname
String password
```

A to B is 1 to many relation.
B to User is 1 to many.

I want to have the list of B's in A.

What is the best approach to solve the situation?

In the net when I search I am just getting information for inverse join for simple columns, if I try that its not working out, so is there a special way to achieve this?

Comment: You already a set of B's in A. Simply use a `@OneToMany` to map them.

Comment: When I use @onetomany annotation. What kind of join conditions I have to give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following mapping configuration:

In the `A` entity class:

```
@Entity(name="A")
class A {
   @Id
   int id;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "bPk.a")
   @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.DELETE })
   Set<B> listB;
}
```

In `CompositebPk`:

```
class CompositebPK {
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false) })
   A a;
   @Column(name="user_name")
   String uname;
}
```

Comment: it worked but getting error at the run time (when fetching the column), "Unknown column 'listb_.a_id' in 'field list'", I am not sure how hiberante constructs the column names, why is it appending with "a" to "id"..

Comment: I added name attribute for the joinColumn annotation with the correct name id, now the name is getting constructed correctly listb_0.id, but still getting the error "Unknown column 'listb0_.id' in 'field list'"

Comment: small mistake from my side, i was giving wrong column name, its corrected now thanks a lot..

Comment: Just to help who is trying the solution, if we specify class 'A' in the composite primary key class then it would go into infinite loop, A has List<B> ==> B has A (CompositebPK) and hence it would keep on going, I changed from class A to integer Id and referenced the ID of class A..this solved the problem..